# Limit FTP connections by area

Tags: debian, ftp, cloud, file-server, proftpd

Is there any (simple) way to deny FTP connections based on the general physical location? I plan to use FTP as a simple cloud storage for me and my friends. I use an odroid c2 (similar to raspberry pi but uses arm64 architecture) running Debian 8 with proftpd and ufw as my firewall. Ftp server runs on a non-standard port which I prefer not to mention here. I want to do this to increase the security of my server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use pam and [geoip](https://github.com/vetinari/pam_geoip) module

> This PAM module provides GeoIP checking for logins. The user can be
>   allowed or denied based on the location of the originating IP address.
>   This is similar to pam_access(8), but uses a GeoIP City or GeoIP
>   Country database instead of host name / IP matching.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this to some extend with CIDR[1] IP ranges since these can be mapped to countries[2].

You can then use an app like *iptables*[3] to control any incoming traffic on any port (independent of the protocol). [This tutorial](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/firewalls/control-network-traffic-with-iptables#whitelistblacklist-traffic-by-address) describes it in some more detail.

In combination with CIDR the command would look something like this:

`iptables -A INPUT -s 64.110.50.0/24 -j ACCEPT`

Depending on how many friends you have, you may be able to narrow this down by the [IP blocks reserved by your friends' Telco/Internet provider](http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/).

(BTW CIDR rules are what Amazon's cloud services use, and they highly recommends to make AWS instances more secure in this manner. So your question has a lot of merit, but since I just joined I cannot up-vote it - or rather my vote doesn't show).

Additional links for reference that I cannot embed as I only get two links to use as a newbee:

1) en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing
2) blog.erben.sk/2014/02/06/country-cidr-ip-ranges
3) en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using ProFTPD's [`mod_geoip`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_geoip.html) module, to at least restrict connections to the geographic content/country (and city, if you can).  This is similar to @Ipor's answer, using the same geoip libraries/databases, except that it doesn't require PAM configurations, and is more flexible.